# onPageSelected is called before onViewCreated

Tags: android

Thats a big problem for me right now because i need to call a method from an interface
all my fragments in my viewpager are implementing. I need to do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    this.getActivity().getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    FragmentVisible fragment = (FragmentVisible) this.fragmentPager.instantiateItem(this.viewPager, position);

    if (fragment != null) {
        fragment.fragmentBecameVisible();
    } 
}
```

This works for the "normal startup" but when i rotate the screen i get nullpointer exceptions
because onPageSelected gets called before onViewCreated. I need my views to get updated everytime
a fragment gets visible. First i hoped onResume would get called everytime but it doesnt. For that 
i implemented the interface:

```
public interface FragmentVisible {
    public void fragmentBecameVisible();
}
```

Does someone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [FragmentPagerAdapter's setPrimaryItem()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java#121) method (called when the `ViewPager` sets the current page), it calls [setUserVisibleHint(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)) for the current page's fragment. You can override that method in your `Fragment` and do your `fragmentBecameVisible()` method in there.

Comment: this is also called before the onCreate or onCreateView. but i guess i can handle it. i will implement setUserVisibleHint and onResume and in setUserVisibleHint i will check my views for being null or not. thanks.